# How to add Show/Hide Password button in Listview ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

```xml
<EditItemTemplate >
    <li style="">username:
        <asp:Label ID="usernameLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("username") %>' />
        <br />
        password:
        <asp:TextBox ID="passwordTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("password") %>' />

        <asp:Button ID="btnClick" OnClick="btnClick_Click" runat="server" Text="Hide/Show" />
        <br />
        email:
        <asp:TextBox ID="emailTextBox"  runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("email") %>' />

        <br />
        phone:
        <asp:TextBox ID="phoneTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("phone") %>' />
        <br />
        dob:
        <asp:TextBox ID="dobTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("dob") %>' />
        <br />
        gender:
        <asp:TextBox ID="genderTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("gender") %>' />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
        <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
    </li>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

For example, in Listview edit item template I want to add that button so how to access that button in code behind file as it is in Listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are developing a website, for any user interface interaction, you are strongly recommended to use javascript,css to manipulate it. Only use code behind to process data.

```js
function toggleShowPassword() {
 var passwordTextBox = document.getElementById('passwordTextBox');
 if(passwordTextBox.getAttribute('type')=='text'){
  passwordTextBox.type='password';
 }
 else {
  passwordTextBox.type='text';
 }
}
```

```css
.button {
line-height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
padding: 7px 15px;
background: #6eddff;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
border-radius: 6px;
}
.button:active,
.button:hover{
background: #3d9dba;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<input id='passwordTextBox' type='password' value='abcd' />
<a class='button' href='#' onclick='toggleShowPassword(); return false;'>
Show/Hide Password</a>
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer, but I have asp.net textbox in listview and from the database it is bind. I am unable to hide and show password in asp.net textbox.

Comment: @RaufMomin [asp.net textbox] is actually converted into [html input type=text], which at the end, works the same at client browser. Try check the html source in chrome or firefox after the page generated. You'll see it. Everything you see "<asp:XXX...." will be converted into HTML elements.

Comment: Yes, it is converted but while coding they both have different attributes like asp.net textbox have attribute Text='<%# Bind("password") %>' which binds it with sqlDataSource so we can easily insert, update and delete but how it is possible in HTML Input?

Comment: @RaufMomin I have made a sample project for you. You may see it and try to understand it for yourself. Here is the file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=12v9iSaNo4MDAr0xdT0EqPM2ggk2cosLV

Answer (score 1):

For displaying the Password, try the following Client-Side approach:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.reveal-eye {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 30px;
  background: #fff url(https://dtzbdy9anri2p.cloudfront.net/cache/b55f544d09a0872a74b4427ce1fe18dd78418396/telerik/img/dist/reveal-password.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s ease 0s, visibility 0s linear .2s;
}

.reveal-eye.is-visible {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .2s ease 0s, visibility 0s linear 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <!--<asp:TextBox ID="passwordTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />-->
    <input type="password" id="passwordTextBox" />
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function checkShowPasswordVisibility() {
        var $revealEye = $(this).parent().find(".reveal-eye");
        if (this.value) {
            $revealEye.addClass("is-visible");
        } else {
            $revealEye.removeClass("is-visible");
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var txtPassword = document.getElementById('passwordTextBox');
        var $revealEye = $('<span class="reveal-eye"></span>')
        $(txtPassword).parent().append($revealEye);
        $(txtPassword).on("keyup", checkShowPasswordVisibility)

        $revealEye.on({
            mousedown: function () { txtPassword.setAttribute("type", "text") },
            mouseup: function () { txtPassword.setAttribute("type", "password") },
            mouseout: function () { txtPassword.setAttribute("type", "password") }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Example originates from: [ShowPassword button for RadTextBox with TextMode Password](https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/textbox/details/showpassword-button-for-radtextbox-with-textmode-password)

However, if you would like to do it on server-side during a PostBack, here is an example showing how to access the TextBox when the Button Show/Hide is clicked:

```cs
protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;

    TextBox TextBox1 = btn.Parent.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;

    TextBox1.TextMode = TextBox1.TextMode == TextBoxMode.Password ? TextBoxMode.SingleLine : TextBoxMode.Password;
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer, it's showing me the exception of nullreferenceexception for TextBox1 in which we have saved.

Comment: TextBox is rendered as Input element. I've commented out the TextBox and added an input so that I can insert a working snippet here. In your case, use the TextBox and ignore that Input. The results should be the same.

Comment: The nullreferenceexception is coming from he server indicating that a part of the logic is trying to access and object that does not exist. That has nothing to do with this the client-side approach I have shared.